# Setting input's placeholder color in footer element is not working

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

everyone!

[edit]

Take a look at the [fiddle I created](http://jsfiddle.net/phpworker/3a8gcxLf), it looks like inside footer element placeholder styling is not working. Any idea how to overcome this?

I tried to use:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
color:    #3d3d3d!important;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #3d3d3d!important;
   opacity:  1!important;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #3d3d3d!important;
   opacity:  1!important;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #3d3d3d!important;
}
:placeholder-shown { /* Standard (https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#placeholder) */
  color:    #3d3d3d!important;
}
```

as well as:

```
footer::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
color:    #3d3d3d!important;
}
```

and it didn't help.

Keep in mind I want a separate color for placeholder text and for input text typed by the user.

Any idea where to start?

Comment: Please include the code for a full reproducible example in your question, instead of linking to an external site.

Comment: its a complicated website but I'll try.

Comment: here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/phpworker/3a8gcxLf/

Comment: I also added another form inside a body element. It looks like inside of `footer` element these stylings are not working...

Answer (score 1):

OK, it was really stupid one. There was a javascript added to `input` element:

```
<input type="text" name="woochimp_widget_subscription[email]" id="woochimp_widget_subscription_email" class="woochimp_widget_field" required="" value="Enter your email..." onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter your email...';" />
```

after removing the js code and adding `placeholder`attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="woochimp_widget_subscription[email]" id="woochimp_widget_subscription_email" class="woochimp_widget_field" required="" value="Enter your email..." placeholder="Enter you email..." />
```

it started to work just nice.

Thank you All for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It may not make a difference, but try moving the comments so that they fall outside the style declarations.

Also, don't forget to include:

```
::-ms-input-placeholder {color: #3d3d3d;}  /* Edge */
```

**Full styles:**

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #3d3d3d;} /* WebKit, Blink and Opera */

:-moz-placeholder {color: #3d3d3d; opacity: 1;} /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */

::-moz-placeholder {color: #3d3d3d; opacity: 1;} /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */

:-ms-input-placeholder {color: #3d3d3d;} /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */

::-ms-input-placeholder {color: #3d3d3d;}  /* Edge */

:placeholder-shown {color: #3d3d3d;} /* CSS Level 4 Selector */
```

Comment: That's disappointing. I have used the same styles above on a recent site of mine and everything worked. Can I ask what browser the styles are not working in?

Comment: sure, I tried it on:Google 
- Chrome Version 48.0.2564.103 m
- Firefox v. 42.0
- IE v. 11.63
- MS Edge v. 25
All on Windows 10 Home (64bit)

Comment: @Rounn take a look at the fiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/phpworker/3a8gcxLf/ it looks like inside `footer` element placeholder styling is not working. Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

```
#coupon_code::-moz-placeholder {
color: #d3d3d3!important;
opacity: 1!important;
}
```

i have change above css line in your fiddle, hope this will help you.

Comment: OK, I just realized that there was js added to the input field in footer. After removing that js your code is not even necessary. Stupid me :)